# Ask name, if wrong ask again, if right, keep going ( Not working ) C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, do-while, password-checker

That's my code. What i'm trying to do here is a code that Asks for a name ( like a pass ) if the name is wrong, then the program says those 3 error messages and asks the name again, until one of the 2 white-listed names is given, then just keep going with the code.

```
int main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
string Name = "";
cout << "Whats your name dude ?" << endl;
cin >> Name;

if (Name == "ighor" ||
    Name == "indio")
    {
    cout << "Welcome friend =D" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    }
    else
    {
        do  
        {
            cout << "Sorry, wrong name =[" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            cout << "I'll give you another chance =]" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            cout << "Write your name again" << endl;
            cin >> Name;

            if (Name == "ighor" ||
                Name == "indio")
            {
                continue;
            }

        }   while (Name != "ighor" ||
                   Name != "indio");


    }

cout << "Whats up" << Name << endl;
system("pause");
system("cls");      
        return 0;

}
```

My tests with this code gave me this :
If i put a white-listed name ( indio or ighor ) i get the massage of correct name

> "Welcome friend =]".

If i put a wrong name, i get the massage of wrong name, nice, then i'm asked to enter the name again, i put one of the white-listed names and it keeps saying that it's the wrong name, wrong names also show wrong name message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in the `do-while` loop is flawed. Instead of

```
            continue;
```

you need

```
            break;
```

`continue;` continues with the next iteration of the loop. `break;` breaks the loop.

Also, the `while` statement logic incorrect. You need to use:

```
while (Name != "ighor" &&  Name != "indio");
                      ^^^ not ||
```

Having said that, you only need one of the checks, not both.

You can use:

```
do  
{
   ...

   if (Name == "ighor" || Name == "indio")
   {
      break;
   }

} while (true);
```

or

```
do  
{
   ...

}  while (Name != "ighor" && Name != "indio");
```

Comment: I watched some videos about break and continue but as you can see i just got it wrong hahaha, thanks man =D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main() {

  string name;
  cout << "Whats your name dude ?" << endl;
  cin >> name;

  while (!(name == "ighor" || name == "indio")) {
    cout << "Sorry, wrong name =[" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    cout << "I'll give you another chance =]" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    cout << "Write your name again" << endl;
    cin >> name;
  }

  cout << "Whats up " << name << endl;
  system("pause");
  system("cls");      
  return 0;
}
```

it's shorted, cleaner, more expressive and it works too..

Answer (score 0):

> **In your code:**

Your condition was `while (Name != "ighor" || Name != "indio");` which means if any of this two conditions is `true` then the Loop will continue it's work.If your input is `"indio"`  then the first condition became `true`.

> **In my code:**

`while (Name != "ighor" && Name != "indio");`which means this two condition must be `true` if one of them became `false` then the loop will stop it's work. Now, if your input is `"indio"` this condition became `false` and your loop will stop.

**To know more about `continue` and `break` statement read [this](http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/break-continue) and [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/58-break-and-continue/).**

> Try This:

```
int main(void)
    {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    string Name = "";
    cout << "Whats your name dude ?" << endl;
    cin >> Name;

    if (Name == "ighor" ||
        Name == "indio")
        {
        cout << "Welcome friend =D" << endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "Sorry, wrong name =[" << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                cout << "I'll give you another chance =]" << endl;
                //system("pause");
                system("cls");
                cout << "Write your name again" << endl;
                cin >> Name;

                if (Name == "ighor" ||
                    Name == "indio")
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }   while (Name != "ighor" &&
                       Name != "indio");


        }

    cout << "Whats up" << Name << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation =D just made it right now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers i did changed

```
continue;
```

for

```
`break;`
```

and it worked perfect =)
But as the code was too confusing i may study a bit the other tips you guys gave me so i can make it cleaner =D
I just have another doubt with this piece of code

```
cin >> RPI;
if (RPI == "Sim"||RPI == "sim"||RPI == "vou"||RPI == "Vou")
```

What i wanted here was to "check" the answer and make something if i was "Sim" or "Vou" which(means "Yes" and "i will", but anyway)
I think that i can use what you guys told me about the "II" replacement for "&&" so it makes the condition correctly.
If there was a way or a command, so it don't differentiate Capital and lowercase just for this answer, so didn't i need to put both ways that the person can write would also help.
Thats just a learning code, only for studding propose

It was the first time i posted and really surprised, those lot of answers and it was too fast, thanks you all for the support.
You guys rule.
Good codding.

Comment: Don't write another question in an answer to a question. It will be better to post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Please indent your code correctly.
Try replacing

```
continue;
```

by

```
break;
```

The continue statement goes through the loop again, what you want to do is exit it. Let me know if it works, as I am not able to test right now.

Comment: Thanks man, i did it, and worked =D i appreciate your concern